# Can Blackbeard consume more than one Devil Fruit?

Tags: one-piece

[image]

Can Blackbeard consume more than just one Devil Fruit? If yes, then what is the upper limit?

When he reaches the maximum number of Devil Fruits, can he change them, i.e. can he lose one of the Devil Fruits to consume a new one?

Comment: up until now, Kurohige only known to eat two devil fruit: Yami Yami no Mi and Gura Gura no Mi. And he didn't lose any devil fruit ability that he already have, instead he can use bot power at the same time.

Comment: A posible theory is that Teech used his darkness devil fruit powers to absorb Whitebeards Yami Yami no mi abilities. We all know its possible for his dakness to swallow all forms of mattter into his void like a blackhole.  He could have figured out how to absorb specific things like devilfruit abilities into himself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Mythbusters](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Mythbusters/Misunderstandings_and_Mistranslations#Eating_two_Devil_Fruits) article on One Piece Wiki:

> ### Eating two Devil Fruits Edit
>
> **Myth:** When you eat 2 Devil Fruits, the second fruit will replace the first fruit's power.
>
> **Fact:** Eiichiro Oda stated in one of his SBS that you cannot transfer the fruit's power to another person, if you take one bite of it the fruit becomes normal. This caused fans to think he meant if you eat the second Devil Fruit it will replace the first fruit but in Enies Lobby Arc, Lucci and Blueno said if you eat the second fruit after eating the first one, your body will explode and you will die.
>
> **Fact:** An exception to the rule stated above is Marshall D. Teach, user of the Yami Yami no Mi fruit, who stole the power of the Gura Gura no Mi fruit through some currently unknown means not related to eating it.

So it seems that normally no human being can eat 2 Devil Fruits. Until now, Blackbeard is the only one with this ability, though I don't know how. Maybe it's related to the "D." in his name.

Looking forward to see more!

Comment: If it was "Will of D" it would apply for Luffy too ...

Answer (score 6):

I think he used the same technique that Dr. Vegapunk used to create (Lasso and Frankfurt). He must have placed the fruit in his rings somehow to be able to use 2 devil fruits. With that being said, Blackbeard technically only has one devil fruit in his body, and he places the other one in his rings on his hands.

Comment: really interesting thinking, this could actually work. Cause we know you can the fruit also to items.

Answer (score 1):

There is still no answer for this, we just know that for an 'abnormality' of his body (Marco refers to this during Marineford). He can eat more than 1 fruit (even if I think that 2 is the limit). We still don't know if he can change or "absorb" other fruits.

Comment: yeah, i remember this, BB is really Tall and Big maybe this is also a reason...

Comment: Lot of people are Huge even more than BB, so i probably isn't this xD

Comment: For your answer: It's almost sure that when a devil fruit user die, the fruit reborn in the nearest same type fruit, so maybe BB (that probably knew what kinda of fruit type was the Gura-Gura no mi, from the book he used to identify the Yami-Yami)(all planned) had that precise fruit and when WB died he had instantly the fruit, and thanks to his still unknown body abnormality he ate it.

Comment: If you look at the quote of the other answer, you can see that BB didn't eat the Gura Gura no Mi, but used some black magic to extract the power. To be honest, it would be quite lame if he would just stand next to WB, wait for the fruit to be reborn and just eat it. This also makes me wonder, that maybe BB can't actually eat other Devil Fruits, but only extract them from dying corpses.

Answer (score 1):

I think Blackbeard can absorb power like it shows when he fights Ace and Luffy. When he absorbs the power when the person dies, he can use their ability. But at Dressrosa, when the person dies, it tells that the devil fruit comes back into the world after the user dies because that's how Sabo obtains Ace's devil fruit.

But I think Blackbeard's power can remove the user's devil fruit permanently from their body because darkness consumes everything as he says.

Comment: LOL I was actually thinking the same exact thing!  His darkness can absorb all things and cancel out devil fruits. He must have possibly also figured out how to use his darkness to absorb the actual fruit abilities from people. Cause remember in Dressrosa when that "All muscle and no brain" burges wanted to capture luffy because of his devil fruit ability.

Comment: If we think about it, why else would Burges want to steal luffys power. And how else could he have done it , if not through Blackbeard,  who had already done something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I read from other forums, I think Blackbeard have multiple personality that is the reason he's able to get 2 DF without problems. And he might get another one or already have based on his 3 skull flag.

Chapter 225:

[image]